# convert number to scientific notation python with a variable

Tags: python, string, variables, jupyter-notebook, format

I want to use `str.format` to convert 2 number to scientific notation raised to the same exponential but the exponential need to be set off the `str.format`.
Example:

```
from math import log10
y=10000
x=round(np.log10(y))
m=10
y="{:e}".format(y)
m="{:e}".format(m)
print(y)
print(m)
```

here I have that m has e = 1 and y e = 4 and what I want is for both to have the same "e". i want to set both to exponencial x.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz oh man, really thx xD I put the aswer at my post, but if u want put yourself I will give u right

Comment: Ok, man, thx you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to calculate this yourself, for example using a helper function which returns a string:

```
def format_exp(x, n):
    significand = x / 10 ** n
    exp_sign = '+' if n >= 0 else '-'
    return f'{significand:f}e{exp_sign}{n:02d}'
```

Explanation:

- `x` is the number to format, and `n` is the power that you want to display;
- `significand` calculates the part to show in front of the `e` by dividing `x` by 10<sup>n</sup> (`10 ** n`);
- `exp_sign` is either `+` or `-`, depending on the value of `n` (to replicate the default behaviour).

Example usage:

```
>>> import math
>>> y = 10000
>>> m = 10
>>> x = math.floor(math.log10(y))  # x = 4
>>> print(format_exp(y, x))
1.000000e+04
>>> print(format_exp(m, x))
0.001000e+04
>>> print(format_exp(y, 1))
1000.000000e+01
>>> print(format_exp(m, 1))
1.000000e+01
```

You can increase the complexity of this function by adding an additional parameter `d` to set the number of decimals printed in the significand part (with a default value of `6` to reproduce the default Python behaviour):

```
def format_exp(x, n, d=6):
    significand = x / 10 ** n
    exp_sign = '+' if n >= 0 else '-'
    return f'{significand:.{d}f}e{exp_sign}{n:02d}'
```

With this function, you can control the number of decimals printed:

```
>>> print(format_exp(y, x))  # default behaviour still works
1.000000e+04
>>> print(format_exp(y, x, 4))
1.0000e+04
>>> print(format_exp(y, x, 1))
1.0e+04
```

Comment: i can solve that way as well, but I wanted to know if it's possible like i wanted. I will wait a bit more, if not i'm going accpet your answer as corret.

Comment: @MiguelGodinho The [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) section of the Python documentation does not mention any possibility of choosing the exponent using the built-in `format` function; the only digits you can enter are `width` (total width of the formatted string, filled with spaces or any other desired character) and `precision` (number of digits after the decimal point).

Comment: I was trying to change precision, maybe another library has what I want

Comment: @MiguelGodinho What do you mean by changing precision? The function `format_exp` can be expanded with some additional mathematics if you want to specify the number of significant digits instead of the number of decimals printed.

Comment: I wanted to say another thing but nvm. I can't find another answer, going to give yours, right.